# Preserve file permissions and symlinks in archive with 7-Zip

Tags: symlink, executable, 7z

I have a directory `test` with three files, `ls -l test`:

```
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 mb mb 16 Jul 25 11:12 regular_file
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mb mb 19 Jul 25 11:02 script.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mb mb 12 Jul 25 11:14 symlink -> regular_file
```

It contains a regular file, a symbolic link, and an executable script.

After archiving this directory with `tar -czf test.tgz test/`, I wanted to extract the three files with 7-Zip:

```
7z x -tgzip test.tgz && 7z x -ttar test.tar
```

Unfortunately, 7-Zip doesn't produce the original files: The script loses its executable bit and `symlink` is not a symbolic link anymore, rather a file containing the text `regular_file`.

```
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 mb mb 16 Jul 25 11:12 regular_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 mb mb 19 Jul 25 11:02 script.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 mb mb 12 Jul 25 12:16 symlink
```

On the other hand, I can extract the files with their permissions and the symlink intact using

```
tar -xzf test.tgz
```

Is there a way to make 7-Zip extract the files as they were before archiving them?

---

7-Zip version is 16.02. I'm on Arch Linux 5.7.7.

[Here's](https://mega.nz/file/Tx43CIpQ#nRaYLcuMDConsNp6CgZDAcbO9ismwIsbRPvCLTyk9t4) the archive created with `tar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation of 7-Zip, judging from these bug reports:

- [#1302 .tar archives fail to extract properly](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/1302/)
- [#1188 symlinks in tar archives are extracted to 0 byte files](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/1188/)

For now, I'll keep using `tar -xzf test.tgz` to extract the files.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually mentioned in the [7z Man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z) that for Unix systems, permissions are not stored by 7-Zip:

> Backup and limitations DO NOT USE the 7-zip format for backup purpose
> on Linux/Unix because : - 7-zip does not store the owner/group of the
> file. On Linux/Unix, in order to backup directories you must use tar :
>
> - to backup a directory : tar cf - directory | 7za a -si directory.tar.7z
> - to restore your backup : 7za x -so directory.tar.7z | tar xf -
>
> If you want to send files and directories (not the owner of file) to
> others Unix/MacOS/Windows users, you can use the 7-zip format.
>
> example : 7za a directory.7z directory
>
> Do not use "-r" because this flag does not do what you think.
>
> Do not use directory/* because of ".*" files (example : "directory/*"
> does not match "directory/.profile")

Thus, you should be able to preserve the owner/group statuses by using it in conjunction with TAR.

Comment: This is rather odd. I am too using "7-Zip [64] 16.02" under Ubuntu (21.04) and the `.7z` file I create ***does*** contain the file access permissions (not tested symlinks). I can even view these ***correct*** permissions under Windows using the "7-Zip 18.06 (x64)" GUI. Of course, these permissions will not be restored to a Windows system, but they are restored correctly on to a Linux system.

Comment: This is not official 7z manual web page. This is just some random page with some obsolete information.